# Fetch steps and execute steps

Tags: cpu, communication, instruction-set

Recently I am doing some self-study about CPU. And I find a exercise question from the book, since the structure of the book is messed up, I am not able to solve this question.

> Instruction, Sub[60][61],copies number stored in address 60 to address 61. Assume instruction is stored at address 70, show the fetch and execute steps.

Please give me a hand.

Comment: I figured out the fetch step just need the execute steps